# Apply fuzzy matching score at two columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I have dataframe:

```
df =
    original_title                     title
      Mexico Oil                    Gas Summit
      Mexico Oil                    Gas Summit
```

I have to fuzzy match the entities of these two(original_title & title) columns and get a score. 
below is my code:

```
compare = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ df['original_title'],df ['title'] ]). to_series()
def metrics (tup):
    return pd.Series([fuzz.partial_ratio(*tup),fuzz.token_sort_ratio(*tup)], ['partial', 'token'])

compare.apply(metrics)
```

The above code compares each original title with the whole column of title. while, I want it to compare each original title with title in each row.
My expected outcome would be:

```
df =
 original_title                    title                 partial_ratio
 Mexico Oil                      Africa Oil                   81
 French Property Exhibition      French                      100
 French Exhibition               French Exhibition           100
```

Would appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `Dataframe`s `apply()` function as follows:

```
df['partial_ratio'] = df.apply(lambda x: fuzz.partial_ratio(x['original_title'], x['title']), axis=1)
```

This gives the results I think you're after (although the numbers are slightly different):

```
...    partial_ratio
...    78
...    83
...    100
...    100
...    100
```